# Plaie sur (le) menton

Tags: articles

J'ai écrit dans l'objet d'un courriel

> plaie sur **le** menton

afin de mentionner le sujet de mon message.

Est-ce que j'aurais dû omettre l'article aussi devant *menton* ?

Comment: Je pense qu'on dit au, comme ici pour une plaie au doigt: https://www.leprogres.fr/sante/2013/10/28/on-ne-peut-pas-envoyer-une-ambulance-pour-une-plaie-au-doigt « On ne peut pas envoyer une ambulance pour une plaie au doigt »
Haute-Loire/Loire. Comment le Samu 42, qui intervient sur l’est de la Haute-Loire, gère-t-il les appels d’urgence ? Explications du docteur Fabrice Granjon.

Comment: *Plaie au menton*, *plaie sur le menton* ou *plaie sous le menton* sont possibles, les deux derniers donnant légèrement plus de précision sur la localisation de la plaie. En style télégraphique, ce pourrait être aussi *Plaie menton* mais ce n'est pas vraiment justifié dans le champ objet d'un courriel puisqu'on ne paye pas au mot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Vu le contexte, non. On n'a pas discuté du choix de la préposition et probablement que la fréquence d'emploi est plus grande avec *à*, mais on peut choisir de mettre l'accent davantage sur la morphologie, la surface (voire suggérer peut-être la superficialité), plutôt que sur l'endroit du corps ; je le mentionne simplement parce qu'on trouve l'article dans la contraction *au*. La question de la concurrence et de la complémentarité des prépositions est un sujet qu'on étudie parfois verbe par verbe etc.

Pour revenir à la question, la raison de ne pas omettre l'article ici est que l'omettre évoque ou représente pour moi soit le toponyme (*Plaie-sur-Menton*), soit le croisement, l'agencement (*bleu sur blanc*, l'héraldique etc.) et la répétition (*épisode sur épisode*), soit le langage plus ou moins enfantin (?), soit finalement la représentation d'un prototype incomplet d'une langue ancienne ou précieuse avec le verbe conjugué (*j'ai plaie sur menton*). Aucune de ces idées ne correspond à ce qu'on veut signifier et exprimer à mon avis. Et c'est donc *a contrario* que je trouve qu'il n'est pas souhaitable d'omettre cet article dans le contexte de la question (médecine).

Comment: Merci. Est-ce que _plaie **au** menton_ est préférable à _plaie **sur** le menton_ ?

Comment: Ça dépend de ce qu'on trouve _préférable_. Si tu cherches sur le web entre guillemets l'un et l'autre, avec _à_ sort 5 fois plus je pense. Sur un ngram on n'atteint pas le plancher avec _sur_. Je trouve les deux clairs, et on peut vouloir exprimer des nuances que j'ai évoquées dans le premier para. de ma réponse. La nuance est illimitée, comme tu sais je suis Montréalais, et il est peu probable que je dise _j'ai une plaie au menton_, mais comme objet d'un courriel je pourrais l'écrire comme tu l'as fait, sans le verbe, avec _sur_ ou avec _à(au)_.

Comment: En tous cas, on préférera *plaie **sur** le nasme* ;-)